# Foursquare API : How to mention a friend in a foursquare checkin or comment?

Tags: foursquare

Via the foursquare website and I'm assuming the foursquare iPhone app you can now mention friends in the checkin shout or comments of a checkin. The friend is then notified of the mention.

How do we markup the shout/comment for sending to the checkins/add or addcomment endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've just made this functionality available to app developers. Visit https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add for information on how to mark up your shouts with mentions.

Comment: @pfhayes how to add friends to a checkin so that they would be checked in as well?